# JavaFXPorts as background service on Android

Tags: javafx, javafxports

**Task**

Basically what I need is to send a request to a server every minute. When the server returns false, nothing should happen. When the the server returns true, a sound should be played.

**Problem**

This usually only works when the program is in the foreground, but it should work all the time.

**Question**

Is it possible to let a javafxports app run on android as background service?

Answer (score 0):

This probably should work. You have the full Android Api with you.
But I don't know how to integrate this with the JAVAFX Port.

I think you need an extra Activity for that, and if you want to show the gui you have to start the JxPort Activity.

Maybe this helps: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html